# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] would return number instead of $_GET value when stored in $_SESSION

Tags: php, get, session-variables, request-uri

I have the following code in first page:

```
$_SESSION['redirect_address'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

when I call `$_SESSION['redirect_address']` in the next page it gives me something like this:

```
/host/example.php?1508270070
```

while it must give me someting like:

```
/host/example.php?url=XYZ
```

When I check the value of `$_SESSION['redirect_address']` at the very end code of the first page it gives me the correct value, while checking the same `$_SESSION['redirect_address']` at the very beginning of the code of the second page it returns the numbers, tried to clear cookies with no luck.

Spent on this 4 hours over the net, and no one could answer my question, please help!

Comment: Are you rewriting urls (Apache/nginx)?

Comment: The server that I'm using is Apatche, those urls are for dynamic pages, I use this technique to let users go to login page then after that get them back to the orginal dynamic page that they clicked on before logging in

Comment: By the way I have another page that uses the same method, when it goes to the login page no problem occurs, although I ise exactly same code for stroing the url and same code exactly to recall it.

Answer (score 0):

## Your NGINX is doing something it probably shouldn't

*...but that's what it is currently configured to do*

1. According to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4), the full path and "query-string" should be included in the URI.
2. According to [PHP $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) documentation, `$_SERVER('REQUEST_URI')` *does not* neccessarily include the query-string. Various server configurations and php versions have very different results regarding what data is stored in this variable, if any.

## Check your environment

Based on your existing environment's configuration, you should probably check what values you are actually getting for the following SERVER variables: `QUERY_STRING`, `ORIG_PATH_INFO`, `PATH_INFO`, `PATH_TRANSLATED`, `SCRIPT_NAME`, `REQUEST_URI`, and `PHP_SELF`.

Adjust your session redirect accordingly.

Comment: Many thanks for the info, there are two different pages, I'm using on-click policy to let google bots to index dynamic web pages, however when the user click on any link the website should save the page, direct the user to login page, then send him/her back to the page which was clicked in the first place, now first page works perfectly fine, the $_SESSION keeps the correct url while the other page (which save urls same way) return the stored link as described in the question, therefor there's nothing wrong with the configuration of the server because the other page works fine.

Comment: @Mostafa, could you be more specific about what you mean by "other page"?

Comment: Your findings still suggest that you should change your implementation, to instead store more granular details in the session, and rebuild the url later.

Comment: I have 2 types of pages each represent different type of service and they are dynamic, beside the login page, since I'm using the on-click policy when user clicks on one of those pages, the server carries the url (full) takes the user to login then redirect to the saves url, one of those pages works perfectly fine, the other returns the numbers as in $_GET parameter, hope this would be much more clear.

Comment: gotcha. there's two things you should try: 1. `print_r` the value of `$_SESSION['redirect_address']` **after** you've populated it. (I suspect that `REQUEST_URI` on that page is _not_ properly populated by nginx. 2. write to a log file EVERY time you write or read `$_SESSION['redirect_address']` in your code (this will _certainly_ lead you to the real cause.)

Comment: I have checked echo $_SESSION['redirect_address'] and print_r($_SESSION) , and I placed them at the end of the first page (that saves the REQUESR_URI, and it shows the correct  value, then at the beginning of the code of the next page directly but it shows me the stored value in wrong format (so two codes run exactly after each other but each one in different page), but I didn't store into log, I'll do that and check the results, thanks.

Comment: you might also want to do a deep-dive search for 'redirect_address', and/or try giving your var a different name. There might be something else using/overwriting the value.